# adjust container width by absolutely positioned inner element or vertical align bottom

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment, absolute

Also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KA2F5/1/).

How can I get the container of an absolute element, adjust its width automatically based on the width of the absolutely positioned element inside it.

Alternatively, the positioning can be removed but it's impossible to get the element (img) be vertically aligned to bottom.

```
ul {}
ul li {min-width:120px;height:200px;border:1px solid;float:left;margin:5px;position:relative;}
ul li img {position:absolute;bottom:0;display:block;}
ul li a {}


<ul>  

<li><a href="#">Andrew</a>
    <span><img src=http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51OcPyDBQ7L._SL160_.jpg></span> </li> 
 <li><a href="#">Splog</a>
     <span><img src=http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51uhWLjlvGL._SL160_.jpg></span></li> 

</ul>
```

Image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can, the parent will not respond to an absolutely positioned child, unless of course you use js, or are willing to make the child positioned relative

Comment: Your HTML is aweful. Ewwww!

Comment: @andrewk, what I need is your credit card number :P. The closing `</li>` should be after the closing `</span>`, not after.

Comment: Yes that is right, I missed it. Sorry about that, I thought you were just trolling and passing bye.

Comment: I hope the answer below was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            ul {}
            li {min-width:120px;height:200px;border:1px solid;float:left;margin:5px;position:relative;display: table;}
            li img {bottom:0;display:block;}
            li a {}
            li span {display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;}
        </style>


        <ul>  
            <li><a href="#">Andrew</a>
                <span><img src=http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51OcPyDBQ7L._SL160_.jpg> </span> </li>
             <li><a href="#">Splog</a>
                 <span><img src=http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51uhWLjlvGL._SL160_.jpg> </span></li>

        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The magic is in the `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: bottom`. You also have to remove the absolute positioning from the image.

Also notice I changed all occurences of `ul li` to `li`? Yes, that's because all `li`s are inside `ul`s!

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for, you are removing the absolute positioning on the image

Comment: @JustinBicknell, you read too fast that you did not get this line in the question "Alternatively, the positioning can be removed but it's impossible to get the element (img) be vertically aligned to bottom."

Comment: @Kizer it does get the job done. :) Goodluck in the Cup of Nations.

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript code (jQuery) will do the trick if you run it after the images have loaded:

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/KA2F5/5/

```
$.each($("ul li"),function(idx,item) {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    var liElement = $(this);
    $.each(liElement.find("img"),function(idx2,imgelem) {
        if($(this).width() > maxWidth) maxWidth = $(this).width();
        liElement.css("width",maxWidth + "px");
    });

});
```